# Is this possible to enable/disable mobile KeyPad programmatically using j2me midp2.0?

Tags: java-me

I am using j2me midp2.0 in Sun Java wireless toolkit 2.5.2. Now I want to enable and disable my mobile keypad programmatically.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, it's not possible. You can't do with j2me.